# Is there a way to increase max_input_vars for php runtime on IBM Bluemix?

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Standard max_input_vars setting is 1000 in the PHP environment. I need to increase this, how I can do this in an app deployed to IBM Bluemix?

Comment: Are you referring to a specific service or to the CLI or ...?

Comment: It would be great if I can set up this in some file with settings, e.g. options.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change default `php.ini` values you have to create a `.user.ini` file in your project root directory and specify the parameter you want to overwrite, for example:

```
max_input_vars = 1500
```

Then push your application again:

```
cf push
```